# Ribbon Connector And Custom Graphics Card

Tags: vga

I understand how to make a homemade VGA connection using resistor ladders or ICs, like is done in this tutorial. http://dqydj.net/how-to-produce-640x480-vga-color-video-from-an-arduino/

Is there any way to use a similar technique for OLED screens or other screens that use the ribbon connector found in this link? https://www.hawkusa.com/manufacturers/newhaven/displays/50-inch-tfts/nhd-50-800480tf-atxl?gclid=Cj0KCQjw6IfoBRCiARIsAF6q06uI0N-zj1bJUuBG-9u-pUYcoLcYHGXPAqGf0xwXN3Kmw2h32FN31-UaAjt9EALw_wcB

Comment: That's not an OLED.  It's really designed for something more the class of a cheap Android tablet or dedicated gadget, not an MCU.  You should look for a display with an integrated frame buffer and an MCU command type interface.

Answer (score 0):

No, the OLED display is completely digital. You will need a microcontroller with lots of digital IO pins to use this display.

Comment: That's not really going to work very well with any MCU *regardless* of pin count; to make good use of that display requires about a megabyte of buffer RAM, which is well beyond what you find in an MCU.  Even running it monochrome would take 48K.  With extreme cleverness one could perhaps generate text mapping on the fly, but it's just the wrong screen to be using.